# Ellipsoid in GraphicsComplex

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to use `Ellipsoid` in a `GraphicsComplex` and I am stuck. My understanding of `GraphicsComplex` is that explicit point coordinate assignments are replaced with integer values pointing to a list of coordinates instead.

So instead of

```
 Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]
```

I can use

```
 Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[{{0, 0, 0}}, Sphere[1, 1]]]
```

instead. Note, that the first argument of `Sphere` is replaced with the first point from the list, i.e. {0,0,0} while the second argument is correctly identified as radius (not coordinate) and not replaced with {0,0,0}.

If I use `Ellipsoid` instead, so instead of

```
Graphics3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 4}]]
```

I use

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[{{0, 0, 0}}, Ellipsoid[1, {2, 3, 4}]]]
```

I get an error:

```
Affine transform 1 should be one of the forms {{{xx, yx, zx}, {xy, yy, zy}, {xz, yz, zz}}, {tx, ty, tz}}; {{xx, yx, zx}, {xy, yy, zy}, {xz, yz, zz}}; or {tx, ty, tz}.
```

and

```
Coordinate index 0 is out of range for the enclosing GraphicsComplex.
```

Two questions: do I use `GraphicsComplex` incorrectly? and is there a simple workaround to feed `Ellipsoid`s to a `GraphicsComplex`?

Answer (score 2):

Note that [`Ellipsoid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid) is rendered by using [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation) under the hood:

```
ToBoxes @ Graphics3D[Ellipsoid[{1,1,1}, {2,3,4}]]
```

> Graphics3DBox[
> InterpretationBox[
> GeometricTransformation3DBox[
> SphereBox[{0, 0, 0}], {{{2, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 4}}, {1, 1, 1}}],
> Ellipsoid[{1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 4}]]]

Basically, a sphere at the origin is translated and transformed by the `GeometricTransformation3DBox` so that it looks like the desired [`Ellipsoid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid). Now, notice that the center of the [`Ellipsoid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid) is part of the transformation argument. Unfortunately, [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex) can only handle coordinate indices when they are inside of a normal graphics primitive, in this case inside of `SphereBox`. This is why [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex) of [`Ellipsoid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid) doesn't work. Consider the corresponding [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex) version:

```
ToBoxes @ Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[{{1,1,1}}, Ellipsoid[1, {2, 3, 4}]]]
```

> Graphics3DBox[
> GraphicsComplex3DBox[{{1, 1, 1}},
> InterpretationBox[
> GeometricTransformation3DBox[
> SphereBox[{0, 0, 0}], {{{2, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 4}}, 1}],
> Ellipsoid[1, {2, 3, 4}]]]]

If `GraphicsComplex3DBox` could understand that the `1` inside the `GeometricTransformation3DBox` represented the point `{1, 1, 1}` then it would render properly. However, it is tricky figuring out what parts of a such a list correspond to a point, and so `GraphicsComplex3DBox` gives up.